# Django (cms) filer is there a way to make it works with SVG files?

Tags: django, django-cms, django-filer

I also tried this:

[djangocms-filer-svg](https://github.com/agcooke/django-filer-svg)

But it seems quite old and impossible to migrate it properly.

```
File "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/introspection.py", line 149, in get_constraints
"foreign_key": tuple(used_cols[0].split(".", 1)) if kind.lower() == "foreign key" else None,
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So I wanted to manipulate directly filer, but whatever I do, it won't allow me to upload SVG files.

Does anyone tried something with django / django-cms filer ?

Comment: What's wrong with `django-filer-svg`? It looks as though you could create a local version and create your own migration file without issue?

Comment: Suggest reading this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-updates/vN_7YHqBcK0/79odlhBgBgAJ